# Add a date column to a data frame

Tags: r, date

I am fairly new to R and I am trying to create a loop to add date column in my data frame that increases by day to a set date.

My data looks like this:

```
'A'  'B'  'C'
 1    2    3
 1    2    3
 4    5    6
 4    5    6
```

I am trying to add a date column so the data looks like this:

```
'A'  'B'  'C'  'Date'
 1    2    3    1/1
 1    2    3    1/1
 4    5    6    1/1
 4    5    6    1/1
 1    2    3    1/2
 1    2    3    1/2
 4    5    6    1/2
 4    5    6    1/2
 1    2    3    1/3
 1    2    3    1/3
 4    5    6    1/3
 4    5    6    1/3
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Your conditions are not clear.  Perhaps `d1 <- expand.grid(1:nrow(df1), paste0("1/", 1:3)); transform(df1[d1$Var1,], Date = d1$Var2)`

Comment: Be more specific about dates. Are you trying to automatically switch months over as in `1/30 1/31 2/1`? If so, you need proper dates including the year. Is there a reason why you are not including the year?

Comment: I was just using those dates as an example. I will be needing a date range from say 2016-01-01 to 2016-12-31.

Comment: Then as Gregor posted `cbind(df1, Date=rep(seq(as.Date("2016-1-1"), as.Date("2016-12-31"), by="day"), each=nrow(df1)))`

Comment: 'Recycling' is unique to R and is simultaneously its greatest asset and most unused benefit. Perhaps Gregor will add a word on how it helps in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To duplicate what is in your question, we'll start by creating your data:

```
df = data.frame(a = c(1,1,4,4), b = c(2,2,5,5), c = c(3,3,6,6))
```

You replicate your data for each value of a string, that takes on values `1/1`, `1/2`, `1/3` and `1/4`

```
# construct the values
values = paste("1", 1:4, sep = "/")
```

If we repeat these values 4 times each (4 being the number of rows in the original data) and add it as a column to the original data, the other rows will be "recycled" - their values repeated - to match the same length:

```
# could change to `each = nrow(df)` to be more general
cbind(df, date = rep(values, each = 4))
#    a b c date
# 1  1 2 3  1/1
# 2  1 2 3  1/1
# 3  4 5 6  1/1
# 4  4 5 6  1/1
# 5  1 2 3  1/2
# 6  1 2 3  1/2
# 7  4 5 6  1/2
# 8  4 5 6  1/2
# 9  1 2 3  1/3
# 10 1 2 3  1/3
# 11 4 5 6  1/3
# 12 4 5 6  1/3
```

These are not dates, they are just strings.

#### Using `Date` class objects

If you want date of class `Date`, they can be created with `as.Date`, and `seq` can be used to create a sequence of `Date`s. By modifying the `values` definition above we can use `Date` class instead, the rest of the code remains the same.

```
values = seq(from = as.Date("2017-01-01"), to = as.Date("2017-01-03"), by = 'day')
```

#### Using `merge` instead of recycling

Another option for combining the data and dates is to use `merge` for a cross join. Using `merge` we don't need to worry about the size of the original data:

```
merge(df, values, all = T)
#    a b c          y
# 1  1 2 3 2017-01-01
# 2  1 2 3 2017-01-01
# 3  4 5 6 2017-01-01
# 4  4 5 6 2017-01-01
# 5  1 2 3 2017-01-02
# 6  1 2 3 2017-01-02
# 7  4 5 6 2017-01-02
# 8  4 5 6 2017-01-02
# 9  1 2 3 2017-01-03
# 10 1 2 3 2017-01-03
# 11 4 5 6 2017-01-03
# 12 4 5 6 2017-01-03
```

This is a little more general, and would be useful if you needed to add multiple columns rather than just a single vector.

Comment: Maybe a sentence on 'recycling'?

Comment: @PierreLafortune yeah, that definitely improved the answer (though I'm tempted to delete the recycling method entirely in favor of `merge`).

Comment: Makes sense, but recycling is important enough to at least mention for new users. Especially if they come from another programming language.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks!

Comment: #Gregor Thomas, thanks for the helpful discussion, but I don't quite understand what you mean when you say "Using merge we don't need to worry about the size of the original data".  Care to comment?

Comment: @WBarker In the first method I show we *"repeat these values 4 times each (4 being the number of rows in the original data)"*. So the code we use depends on the size of the original data. In the `merge` method the code does not depend on or reference the size of the original data.

Comment: @Gregor Thomas Got it!  Thanks.